# How to structure account balance system

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, architecture

This is more of a theoretical question on how to structure a user accounting balance architecture. For the stack we are probably going to use Symfony with Doctrine, but I don't think that the language is most relevant.

The problem:

We need to create and maintain a usage balance for each user for our rest API to be used for billings.

There are three types of billings:

1. Fixed price, such as yearly/monthly
2. Post pay usage based per API call.
3. Pre pay usage based per API call.

And a mix of these on the same account. API calls can have different prices.

The problem is not as simple as having a SQL table with a column that says "balance" and update this. We need to log the deposits and withdrawals on the account and track every API call and usage for auditing. So this means we probably need a transactions table.

So this is where I need advice. For large scale applications, should we put every single users transaction in the same table, then use SQL to summarize the balance per date? This table could become enormous after a short while. 1 million API calls = 1 million rows.

We could probably utilize some kind of debit/credit solution. So that when an invoice is paid the order system will add a positive balance to this account. And when an API call is made it debits depending on the price.

Since we have 3 different billing models we may use some kind of tag that says that "API call 1 2 3 are fixed price and API call 4 5 6 are paid per usage".

If it is on post pay the balance will go negative.

On each billing run the order system will ask the balance system how much to invoice.

Any thoughts on how to structure this in a sane way?

Answer (score 3):

You might get more/better answers if you define criteria for "sane".

The canonical model for this is indeed a transactions table. Ignoring performance concerns for a moment, a transaction table gives you a bunch of benefits:

- every action is logged, so you can easily see how the current account balance came to be.
- you can easily see what the account balance was at an arbitrary point in the past.
- it's easy manage at the point where the transaction is created - you just insert a new row into the transaction table, rather than having to execute a bunch of complex business logic to find the current user's balance, work out the appropriate pricing model, and then modify the balance, all the while maintaining a transaction/lock to avoid concurrent writes

So, I'd recommend the "transaction table" model.

As for practical concerns - yes, they can grow rather quickly. Luckily, SQL databases are pretty good at handling large numbers of records, and in a well-designed database, hundreds of millions of rows are not a particular challenge. However, there are some common strategies to avoid huge numbers of records.

Most commonly, you can write an archiving procedure. Typically, on "post pay" accounts, for instance, when the customer pays an invoice, you write all the transactions covered in that invoice to an archive table, and replace them in your transaction table with a single row. You can do the opposite for a post-pay customer.

You can also partition the logic over time - one system I worked on had a view called "transactions", which was a thin layer over a time-based table schema Every month, the IT department would drop and re-create the view to point at tables called e.g jan2014, feb2014 etc. They would populate each customer's opening balance in those monthly tables. This worked surprisingly well, even though it is clunky and requires down-time at month end.

You could partition over customer type - 3 transaction tables, rather than one big table.